# Modify/Remove HTTP response headers using WinInet

Tags: c++, http, hook, wininet

Hooking WinInet it is possible to have access to the HTTP response through the [Wininet::InternetReadFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103(v=vs.85).aspx) method, but the `lpBuffer` does not include HTTP response headers.

Although I can read response headers ([Wininet::HttpQueryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384238(v=vs.85).aspx)), I am not being able to modify or remove them.

Is it possible to modify/remove HTTP response headers using the Wininet hooks?

There's a way to access the full HTTP response buffer from some Wininet hook?

Comment: Why do you want to modify/remove HTTP response headers? What are you trying to accomplish? What's the problem?

Comment: **Why**: I am doing research; **What**: modify/remove HTTP response headers; **The problem**: I can read HTTP response headers but I can not find any documentation regarding removing or modifying them

Comment: There is no point in doing so.

Comment: Hi @Henrik, we totally disagree whether "there's no point in doing so", nevertheless as it adds nothing to my question, I hope we both agree that it doesn't worth to discuss it further.

Answer (score 0):

u can't , cz the http response headers is acually came from the server reply !

but if u mean that u want hook Wininet::HttpQueryInfo function to fill the http headers response with fake data , sure u can with create a hook like

```
BOOLAPI _stdcall HookedHttpQueryInfoW(
_In_ HINTERNET hRequest,
_In_ DWORD dwInfoLevel,
_Inout_updates_bytes_to_opt_(*lpdwBufferLength, *lpdwBufferLength) __out_data_source(NETWORK) LPVOID lpBuffer,
_Inout_ LPDWORD lpdwBufferLength,
_Inout_opt_ LPDWORD lpdwIndex
);
WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)FuncAddress, FuncOriginalBytes, sizeof(FuncOriginalBytes), &bytesWritten);
```

HttpQueryInfo use Handler to retrieve the http headers , so here u can do an other request to ur web that u customized its return headers , and set it as constant in the return of the real function (modify the hrequest with ur request handler)

```
return HttpQueryInfoW(
    _In_ HINTERNET MyHandler,
    _In_ DWORD dwInfoLevel,
    _Inout_updates_bytes_to_opt_(*lpdwBufferLength, *lpdwBufferLength) __out_data_source(NETWORK) LPVOID lpBuffer,
    _Inout_ LPDWORD lpdwBufferLength,
    _Inout_opt_ LPDWORD lpdwIndex
    );
```

now , if u call

```
HttpQueryInfoW(hrequest, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, lpOutBuffer,&dwSize,NULL);
```

it will be

```
HttpQueryInfoW(MyHandler, HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF, lpOutBuffer,&dwSize,NULL);
```

by the way there is a various tricks ; but this seems easy for me to explain and in its steps

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32110421)